# Can MAPE values change after inverse tranform of target?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, python, mape

I have tranformed my Target variable as following Maxmin transformation and used an engine to get prediction for a time series data. The target transformation is done using the following formula in Python.

```
Max = 5412
Min = 0
y.trans = (y-max)/(min - max)
```

I'm calculating my MAPE as following: `SUM(ABS(predicted - Target))/SUM(Target)`

However when I calculate MAPE with the below values with transformed scale and then inverse transform to original scale, the value changes.

In case of scaled values I get the MAPE as **0.016**
In case of inverse transformed to original scale I get the value **1.403**

Can you help me understand why this would be the case? shouldn't MAPE be same in both the cases? Please ignore the colors in the table.

```
   Target Original| Target Transformed |Predicted Transformed Scale|    Predicted Original Scale
    0                    1                 0.984760045                    82.47863646
    0                    1                 0.985348307                    79.29496252
    0                    1                 0.986776916                    71.56333061
    0                    1                 0.986517592                    72.9667921
    0                    1                 0.98946835                     56.9972898
    0                    1                 0.989874186                    54.80090537
    264              0.951219512           0.991295546                    47.10850505
    60               0.988913525           0.99119119                     47.67327972
    0                    1                 0.988430027                    62.61669388
    480             0.911308204            0.98764636                     66.85789968
    0                    1                 0.986962233                    70.560395
    0                    1                 0.98922508                     58.31386704
    0                    1  '              0.986643061                    72.28775387
    0                    1                 0.988411587                    62.71649116
    0                    1                 0.988002631                    64.92976103
    0                    1                 0.986578411                    72.63763967
    0                    1                 0.989387047                    57.43730164
    12             0.997782705             0.988696028                    61.17709646
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer can be found by doing a bit of math.
However I would like to point out that your definition of MAPE is not the conventional one.

First, in general we remove the max and not the min. Second the formula is the following (the division is per sample):

[image]

But ok let's go back to you calculation:

`SUM(ABS(predicted - Target))/SUM(Target)`

For simplicity let's call $p$ the prediction, $t$ the target, $ps$ the prediction scaled and $ts$ the target scaled using the method you described, $M$ the max and $m$ then min.

Then you have `MAPE = SUM(ABS(p - t))/SUM(t)` for the unscaled version

And `MAPEs = SUM(ABS(ps - ts))/SUM(ts)` for the scaled version

By re-arranging MAPEs you can find that:

`MAPEs = SUM(ABS(p - t))/SUM(t-M)`

You can clearly see that MAPEs and MAPE differs because of that $-M$ left

Comment: Is it ok to use such Maxmin transformation instead of the conventional one where we do Target - min in the denominator?? Also, my MAPE formula is different as I have a lot of zeros in my Target, I get divide by zero error if I use the conventional formula here.

Comment: Any scaling is ok, it depends on your problem. In the end, you will have a value between 0 and 1 because you divide by a negative number (min - max), except that in your case 0 correspond to the max value and 1 to the min value. 
If my response is ok, please note it as the correct answer, Thanks.